# How to add additional rest routes to a nested resource in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, routes, nested-resources

I have a widget that has many links. In the routes file:

```
map.resources :widgets, :has_many => [:links]
```

I want to add a "sort" action to links. What do I need to add to the routes file, so I can write `sort_widget_links_path(widget)`

Comment: Sorting is not in any way RESTful. IMO, you should ideally be specifying the sort order using a query string (e.g. `/widgets/2/links?sort=date&sort_order=asc`) rather than as a URI component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define it using a block:

```
map.resources :widgets do |widget|
  widget.resources :links, :member => {:sort => :get}
end
```

Comment: Hi Mark, thank you for your response. Is it ok to define map.resources :widgets twice or do I have to put everything else related to the widgets routes in the same block?

Comment: Hi deb. You should really use the same block; though I would probably be ok to do otherwise I can't really understand why you would want to. What else is it you need to define?